# Existence of a cyclic vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V \to V$ be a linear operator, and suppose $V$ is $n-$dimensional over a field $\mathbb{F}$. Let $W$ be a non-zero proper $T- $invariant $k-$dimensional subspace of $V$. Suppose that $f_T(0)\neq0$. Show that if $T$ has a cyclic vector, then $T|_W:W \to W$ also has a cyclic vector.

my idea which failed : V has a cyclic vector $\beta$, which necessarily must not be in $W$ ,such that $\{g(T)\beta \  | \  g\in\mathbb{F}[x]\}=V$, let $\alpha_0 \in W$ be a non-zero vector (maybe I have to choose a special $\alpha_0$ ... ), then $\exists h\in \mathbb{F}[x]$ such that $h(T)(\beta)=\alpha_0$. I want to claim that $\mathcal{B}=\{\alpha_0, T(\alpha_0),T^2(\alpha_0), \ldots,T^{k-1}(\alpha_0)\}$ are linearly independent. $f_T(0)\neq0$ implies that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$ and it means that $Null(T)=\{0\}$, therefore all elements of $\mathcal{B}$ are non-zero. Now suppose $$\lambda_0 \alpha_0+\lambda_1T(\alpha_0)+\ldots+\lambda_{k-1}T^{k-1}(\alpha_0)=0$$ $$\Downarrow$$ $$\lambda_0 h(T)(\beta)+\lambda_1Th(T)(\beta)+\ldots+\lambda_{k-1}T^{k-1}h(T)(\beta)=0$$ $$\Downarrow$$ $$h(T)[\lambda_0 (\beta)+\lambda_1T(\beta)+\ldots+\lambda_{k-1}T^{k-1}(\beta)]=0$$ If I knew that $Null \ h(T) =\{0\}$, then $\lambda_0=\lambda_1=\ldots=\lambda_k=0$ but I dont't ...

I appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$I=\{g(x) |g(T)\beta \in W \}$$
$I$ is an ideal, $F[x]$ is a principle ideal domain, so assume $I=(g(x))$.
Then $g(T)\beta$ is a cyclic vector for $W$ for if $f(T)\beta \in W$ then $g|f$ so $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ and $f(T)\beta=h(T) g(T)\beta$.